# Why matplotlib give the error [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x111fa5588>]?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm programming in python and I work on OS Yosemite with Anaconda: Conda Version: 3.15.1, Python Version: 3.4.3.final.0 and I have this problem with plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
a=[1,2,3] 
b=[10,20,30]
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

but I have the error: []. I read some other question about the same problem but I have not resolved my problem.
Thanks in advance.
Giuseppe

Comment: What error exactly you face? I suppose you don't have necessary libraries installed to draw a plot, but that is only an assumption.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the *full* traceback.

Comment: I didn't have any error, it simply just printed`[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x297b57d1f40>]` without showing the plot.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this before import

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 3):

That isn't an error message. plt.plot returns a list of matplotlib.lines.Line2D objects. That object gets printed by the interpreter as:

`<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at ...>`

This format is how the interpreter prints everything that doesn't have a method __repr__.

Its exactly the same as this example

```
>>> def f():
...     return 42
... 
>>> f()
42
```

Possibly these two classes might be a bit more illuminating:

```
>>> class C():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.meaning_of_life = 42
... 
>>> class D():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.meaning_of_life = 42
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Meaning = {}".format(self.meaning_of_life)
... 
>>> C()
<__main__.C object at 0x7f4a3255b8d0>
>>> D()
Meaning = 42
```

If the plot isn't showing then there is a problem elsewhere but it isn't related to that message (which should get printed after you call plt.plot not plt.show anyway).

Answer (score -2):

You might want to install matplotlib

```
pip install matplotlib
```

or on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Then, your code prints a simple line graph on my machine.

Comment: I installed matplot lib with the command pip install matplotlib, restarting anaconda and spyder now graph are visualized but I still have the message: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10ff8f898>].